# Making n characters SSN numbers based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to make SSN numbers in 6.5 row. SSN number will be based on other column in dataframe [ClientID].

Requirements for SSN:

- 9 chars long,
- starts with ClientID with mixed lenght for eg. 1234
- then if client id is shorter than 6 digits fill with zeros but left 3 spots at the end so our egzample now will be 123400
- ends with 999, so our egzample finally is 123400999

I found the way for creating an SSN number for fixed lenght ClientIDs but I don't know how can I make it for various lenghts CleintIDs. I'm operating on 6.5k rows so method needs to be efficient. I will be grateful for any ideas how can I make it?
Regards,
Ed.

Comment: Please tell my why You are '-' this post at least so I will know what should i change in the future.

Comment: First, I haven't voted this question down.  But to offer one explanation: hover the cursor over the downvote button and read the tooltip.  That explains it.  I would suggest this particular question is read by some as 'do all my work for me as i cannot be bothered'. A Stackflow question is best posted as: clear succinct goal + restraints (have to use JSON input, or must be Python 2.8 etc.) + code so far + current output with problems highlighted and why it's a problem (if not obvious/how it differs from the goal) + desired outcome in a perfect world.  Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
def ssn(clientID):
    num_zeros = 6-len(clientID)
    rv = clientID+num_zeros*'0'+'999'
    return rv

df["ssn"] = df["clientID"].apply(ssn)
```